# Xcode 4.2 IOS 5, No keyboard showing up for uitextview

Tags: ios5, keyboard

I have a uitextview that working fine on iOS 4 and when i passed to iOS 5 the keyboard does not shown.

if i add : [self.view.window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
==>- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView ---> run
else
 not

but since i passed to iOS 5 (simulator/device) the keyboard does not shown.

Can someOne help?